# Fastest way to load / display bitmap; best way to reuse Bitmap

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I need to display images at different frames per second, maxim FPS being 30. The images are from SDcard and all have the same size: 480 x 640.
I have created 3 possible solutions, but each have problems:

The below results are at 30 FPS.

**I. Not reusing the bitmap**

- lots of GC calls: aprox. **30 GC per second**
- CPU load: reach up to **92%**

  ```
  private Bitmap bitmap;

  private void startAnimation1() {
      TimerTask updateImage = new UpdateImage1();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateImage, 0, 1000 / FPS);
  }

  class UpdateImage1 extends TimerTask {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          try {
              if (i == IMAGES_NR) {
                  i = 0;
              }
              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(framesFiles[i]), null, null);
              i++;
          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              System.out.println("Exception 1: " + e.getMessage());
          }

          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```

**II. Bitmap reuse via BitmapFactory.Options.inBitmap**

- GC calls is lower - **1 or 2 per second**
- CPU load: reach up to **84%**

After a wile running the animation the app crashes:

```
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=-5131855; regionStart=0; regionLength=1024
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1731)
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): at com.example.SendPreviewOptimization.MyActivity$UpdateImage2.run(MyActivity.java:148)
06-20 15:08:58.158: WARN/System.err(7880): at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
06-20 15:08:58.168: DEBUG/skia(7880): ---- read threw an exception
06-20 15:08:58.168: DEBUG/skia(7880): --- decoder->decode returned false
06-20 15:08:58.168: WARN/System.err(7880): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem decoding into existing bitmap
06-20 15:08:58.168: WARN/System.err(7880): at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:590)
06-20 15:08:58.168: WARN/System.err(7880): at com.example.SendPreviewOptimization.MyActivity$UpdateImage2.run(MyActivity.java:148)
06-20 15:08:58.168: WARN/System.err(7880): at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
06-20 15:08:58.178: ERROR/msm8960.hwcomposer(330): prepareBypass: Unable to setup bypass due to non-pmem memory
06-20 15:08:58.198: ASSERT/libc(7880): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xffd1d447 (code=1)
06-20 15:08:58.238: ERROR/msm8960.hwcomposer(330): prepareBypass: Unable to setup bypass due to non-pmem memory
06-20 15:08:58.498: ERROR/MP-Decision(1448): DOWN Ld:25 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 rq:0.000000 seq:194.000000
06-20 15:08:58.708: INFO/DEBUG(27660): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***



    private static BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions;
    private FileInputStream in;

    private void startAnimation2() {
        bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // setup bitmap reuse options:
        bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
        bitmapOptions.inBitmap = reusableBitmap;
        bitmapOptions.inMutable = true;
        bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        TimerTask updateImage = new UpdateImage2();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateImage, 0, 1000 / FPS);
    }

    class UpdateImage2 extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (i == IMAGES_NR) {
                    i = 0;
                }

                //** version 1:
                in = new FileInputStream(framesFiles[i]);
                //decode into existing bitmap
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, bitmapOptions);
                in.close();

                //** version 2:
                //BitmapFactory.decodeFile(framesFiles[i].getAbsolutePath(), bitmapOptions);

                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception 2: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(reusableBitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**III. Option III: using Buffers**  (One thing that makes `Bytebuffer` more efficient is using direct memory.)

- this option I could not make it work :(

  ```
  private ByteBuffer buffer;
  private byte[] b;
  private IntBuffer mPixels;

  private void startAnimation3() {
      buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(480 * 640 * 6);
      b = new byte[480 * 640 * 6];
      TimerTask updateImage = new UpdateImage3();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateImage, 0, 1000 / FPS);
  }

  class UpdateImage3 extends TimerTask {
      public void run() {
          try {
              if (i == IMAGES_NR) {
                  i = 0;
              }
              FileInputStream frameInputStream = new FileInputStream(framesFiles[i]);
              frameInputStream.read(b);
              buffer.wrap(b);
              buffer.position(0);
              reusableBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
              frameInputStream.close();
              i++;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Exception 3: " + e.getMessage());
          }
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  imgView.setImageBitmap(reusableBitmap);
              }
          });
      }
  }

  private ByteBuffer copyToBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
      int size = bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getRowBytes();
      ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size);
      bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
      return buffer;
  }
  ```

---

At each of the above solutions I receive in logcat lots of

```
ERROR/msm8960.hwcomposer(330): prepareBypass: Unable to setup bypass due to non-pmem memory
```

which I do not know what exactly means.

I haven't worked before with Bitmap reuse and do not know which is the best solution.

I've added the project I've created here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3xov369u1bmjpd1/qBQax4t48D and also 2 frames/images.

**Answer to Neron T**

I've tried that library:

```
    //Option IV:
    private AQuery aquery;

    private void startAnimation4() {
        aquery = new AQuery(this);
        aquery.id(R.id.imgView);

        TimerTask updateImage = new UpdateImage4();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(updateImage, 0, 1000 / FPS);
    }

    class UpdateImage4 extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (i == 29) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //load image from file, down sample to target width of 300 pixels
                        aquery.image(framesFiles[i],300);
                    }
                });
                i++;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception 4: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

It doesn't work as I expected - I have a flickering efect before each picture. I think first it clears the pictures and after that adds a new one :(

Answer (score 0):

Notice you can't modify views from inside threads not being the UIThread (main one), try using AsyncTasks. An easy way to use images without having to think too much is using a framework like Android Query, take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading).

If you want to do it by hand check [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) and [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).

Comment: Thanks first.I'm using `runOnUiThread` method. The context in my app is more complex that the one from the above example. I will try  `ImageLoading` jar file from the link you provided (more exactly the option to load image from a file asynchronously), but an answer to the versions I've exposed in my question are more than welcome.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you ran it onUIThread and i was asking myself why it didn't give that kind of error. Hope the library works for you.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the results of using that library.